# Windows 8.1 PasswordVault.Add exception: The maximum number of credentials that may be stored has been exceeded

Tags: windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm using the Windows 8.1 Preview (from ISO not update) and trying to get some of my Windows Store App code (c#) running in VS2013 but I am getting an exception while using PasswordVault:

"The maximum number of secrets that may be stored in a single system has been exceeded.
The maximum number of credentials that may be stored has been exceeded"

Specifically the .Add line of this code:

```
PasswordCredential cred = new PasswordCredential();
cred.UserName = user;
cred.Password = pass;
cred.Resource = uniqueString;
PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
vault.Add(cred);
```

I have tried switching to a local account but it throws the same exception.  I haven't installed any other apps except the baseline load the OS comes with.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The project I am building is targeted to Windows 8.
I have also tried installing a version built on Windows 8 and it exhibits the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in the credential manager to see how many of your credentials are stored there. Remove some of them and try again?

open control panel-> credential manager

Comment: In fact there were 163 (I suppose this is the maximum) stored in the Vault - I see that these are roamed so it was an unfortunate co-incidence that it reached the maximum just as I was testing it on Windows 8.1.  As an aside I found them by adding some code to the project to RetrieveAll() but they do show up in the credential manager as you point out.